# The term 'nginx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet (windows)

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-code, nginx

I have docker setup and pulled the nginx image yet when I try to run `nginx -v` to get the nginx version it ends up giving me the error in the title as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwYiy.png)

how do I solve this?

expected result: `nginx: version`